# Drag and Drop with resizing browser window (react-use-gesture)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, drag-and-drop

I used hook useDrag from 'react-use-gesture'.

```
 const drag = useDrag((params) => {},
        {
            bounds: {...bounds}
        }
    )
```

I use bounds in full **clientWidth.**

It works fine with constant bounds. But after resizing browser window (open devtools panel in my case) hook use previous offset value(I need to drag all width of resizing clientWidth).

How can I use **useDrag** with **document.body.clientWidth**?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. If we need dynamic bounds we can rewrite values in hook callback

```
 const bind = useGesture({
            onDrag: (params) => {
                      params._bounds[0] = [1, smth1];

                      if (params.offset[0] > smth2) {
                          params.lastOffset[0] = smth2
                          params.offset[0] = smth2
                      }
})
```